# @EnvironmentObject with parent child classes

Tags: ios, inheritance, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to create a global loader which needs to work across all loading activity in the app. Created a baseStore with loading property which holds the boolean indicator for whole app. All other stores inherit BaseStore.

When trying to update the published variable from child views its not updating header indicator. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
class BaseStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false

}


class ChildStore: BaseStore {
    func update(){
        super.isLoading = true
    }
}
```

somewhere in the view

```
import SwiftUI

struct HeaderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var baseStore: BaseStore
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if(baseStore.isLoading == true){
            ProgressView()
                .scaleEffect(0.6, anchor: .center).progressViewStyle(ConfiguredProgressViewStyle())
        }
        
    }
}

struct HeaderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return HeaderView()
            .environmentObject(BaseStore());
    }
}



 struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var childStore: ChildStore
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
    }.onAppear(perform: {childStore.update()})
}
```

Comment: add '@ObservedObject to the parent view

struct yourappApp{
'@ObservableObject var baseStore = BaseStore()
}
var body: some Scene {
WindowGroup {
MainView()
     . environment(baseStore)

.....
}
}

Comment: Added doesnt work